# DoubleRenderError when delivering message with mail_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internal-server-error, mail-form

The following code sample is part of a Rails 3.2.16 app running on Ruby 1.9.3p484.
Whenever a new location is created or one is updated a message should be sent as defined in the `after_filter`.

```
class LocationController < InheritedResources::Base

  respond_to :json

  after_filter :notify_location_contact, only: [:create, :update]

  def create
    @location.user = current_user if current_user
    create!
  end

  def update
    update!
  end


  private

  def notify_location_contact
    message = MailForm.new
    deliver_location_message(message)
  end

  def deliver_location_message(location_message)
    begin
      if location_message.deliver
        render json: { message: "Successfully delivered" }, status: 201
      else
        render json: { error: "Delivery failure" }, status: 500
      end
    rescue => e
      if e.is_a?(ArgumentError)
        render json: { error: "Invalid Recipient" }, status: 422
      else
        render json: { error: e.message }, status: 500
      end
    end
  end

end
```

The message itself is sent. Though, `deliver_location_message` first renders the "Successfully delivered" block and after the last block rendering the error message. This causes an internal server error:

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error
>
> AbstractController::DoubleRenderError - Render and/or redirect were
>   called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only
>   call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that
>   neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if
>   you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something
>   like "redirect_to(...) and return".

For sending the message the [mail_form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form) `~> 1.5.0` is used.

The DoubleRenderError seems to happen because `create` and `update` both render the JSON response when they finished there work. After, `.deliver` renders its JSON response to inform about success or failure.

Answer (score 0):

As the error points out you need to return after calling `render` because you have multiple calls to `render` in your `deliver_location_message(message)` method.  The reason for the error is because Rails continues execution until the end of the method regardless of render or redirect.

Please try the following.  Note the `return` on each `render` line.

```
  def deliver_location_message(message)
    begin
      if message.deliver
        # Here
        return render json: { message: "Successfully delivered" }, status: 201
      else
        # Here
        return render json: { error: "Delivery failure" }, status: 500
      end
    rescue => e
      if e.is_a?(ArgumentError)
        # Here
        return render json: { error: "Invalid Recipient" }, status: 422
      else
        # Here
        return render json: { error: e.message }, status: 500
      end
    end
  end
```

Alternative syntax to:

```
return render json: { message: "Successfully delivered" }, status: 201
```

is:

```
render json: { message: "Successfully delivered" }, status: 201 and return
```

Comment: @JJD, could you post your full trace in your question?